# How to UNinstall ImageMagick on mac os x Lion?

Tags: imagemagick, osx-lion

I installed by mistake ImageMagick for Mac OS X mountain lion on my Lion OS.
How do I uninstall clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14274

Try that way of uninstalling. While it may be a little work that is probably you're best shot.